# Grape rescue Grape::Exceptions::ValidationErrors not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-grape, grape-api

I wrote an api to upload a image file to server.
when I am upload without a file, it will be error

I tried to rescue it like this:

`rescue_from Grape::Exceptions::ValidationErrors do |e|
  error! e.message, 404
end`

but it doesn't work.
Here is error message:

`` E, [2015-11-23T22:17:44.337050 #10646] ERROR -- : avatar is invalid (Grape::Exceptions::ValidationErrors) 
         remote_address: 127.0.0.1
         token: Basic bGl4aWJveDpsaXhpYXBpMTIzNA==
         method: POST
         path: /api/v1/users/change_avatar.json
         query: {"avatar"=>"undefined"}
/Users/macstore1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.6@lixibox/gems/grape-0.13.0/lib/grape/endpoint.rb:249:in `block in run'
/Users/macstore1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.6@lixibox/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:166:in `instrument'
/Users/macstore1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.6@lixibox/gems/grape-0.13.0/lib/grape/endpoint.rb:219:in `run'
/Users/macstore1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.6@lixibox/gems/grape-0.13.0/lib/grape/endpoint.rb:201:in `block in call!'
/Users/macstore1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.6@lixibox/gems/grape-0.13.0/lib/grape/middleware/base.rb:24:in `call'
/Users/macstore1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.6@lixibox/gems/grape-0.13.0/lib/grape/middleware/base.rb:24:in `call!'
/Users/macstore1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.6@lixibox/gems/grape-0.13.0/lib/grape/middleware/base.rb:18:in `call'
/Users/macstore1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.6@lixibox/gems/grape-0.13.0/lib/grape/middleware/base.rb:24:in `call!'
/Users/macstore1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.6@lixibox/gems/grape-0.13.0/lib/grape/middleware/base.rb:18:in `call'
/Users/macstore1/projects/lixibox/app/controllers/api/v1/api_error_handler.rb:9:in `call!'
/Users/macstore1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.6@lixibox/gems/grape-0.13.0/lib/grape/middleware/base.rb:18:in `call'
/Users/macstore1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.6@lixibox/gems/grape-0.13.0/lib/grape/middleware/error.rb:27:in `block in call!'
/Users/macstore1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.6@lixibox/gems/grape-0.13.0/lib/grape/middleware/error.rb:26:in `catch'
/Users/macstore1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.6@lixibox/gems/grape-0.13.0/lib/grape/middleware/error.rb:26:in `call!'
/Users/macstore1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.6@lixibox/gems/grape-0.13.0/lib/grape/middleware/base.rb:18:in `call'
/Users/macstore1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.6@lixibox/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/head.rb:13:in `call'
/Users/macstore1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.6@lixibox/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:153:in `call'
/Users/macstore1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.6@lixibox/gems/grape-0.13.0/lib/grape/endpoint.rb:202:in `call!'
/Users/macstore1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.6@lixibox/gems/grape-0.13.0/lib/grape/endpoint.rb:190:in `call'
/Users/macstore1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.6@lixibox/gems/rack-mount-0.8.3/lib/rack/mount/route_set.rb:152:in `block in call'
/Users/macstore1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.6@lixibox/gems/rack-mount-0.8.3/lib/rack/mount/code_generation.rb:96:in `block in recognize'
/Users/macstore1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.6@lixibox/gems/rack-mount-0.8.3/lib/rack/mount/code_generation.rb:75:in `optimized_each'
/Users/macstore1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.6@lixibox/gems/rack-mount-0.8.3/lib/rack/mount/code_generation.rb:95:in `recognize'
/Users/macstore1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.6@lixibox/gems/rack-mount-0.8.3/lib/rack/mount/route_set.rb:141:in `call'
/Users/macstore1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.6@lixibox/gems/grape-0.13.0/lib/grape/api.rb:114:in `call'
/Users/macstore1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.6@lixibox/gems/grape-0.13.0/lib/grape/api.rb:44:in `call!'
/Users/macstore1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.6@lixibox/gems/grape-0.13.0/lib/grape/api.rb:39:in `call'
/Users/macstore1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.6@lixibox/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:51:in `serve'
/Users/macstore1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.6@lixibox/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:43:in `block in serve'
/Users/macstore1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.6@lixibox/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:30:in `each'
/Users/macstore1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.6@lixibox/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:30:in `serve'
/Users/macstore1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.6@lixibox/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:819:in `call'
/Users/macstore1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.6@lixibox/gems/omniauth-1.2.2/lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:186:in `call!'
/Users/macstore1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.6@lixibox/gems/omniauth-1.2.2/lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:164:in `call'
/Users/macstore1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.6@lixibox/gems/warden-1.2.3/lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `block in call'
/Users/macstore1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.6@lixibox/gems/warden-1.2.3/lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch'
/Users/macstore1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.6@lixibox/gems/warden-1.2.3/lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
/Users/macstore1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.6@lixibox/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/etag.rb:24:in `call'
/Users/macstore1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.6@lixibox/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:38:in `call'
/Users/macstore1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.6@lixibox/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/head.rb:13:in `call'
/Users/macstore1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.6@lixibox/gems/remotipart-1.2.1/lib/remotipart/middleware.rb:27:in `call'
/Users/macstore1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.6@lixibox/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
/Users/macstore1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.6@lixibox/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:260:in `call'
/Users/macstore1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.6@lixibox/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
/Users/macstore1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.6@lixibox/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
/Users/macstore1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.6@lixibox/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:560:in `call'
/Users/macstore1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.6@lixibox/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in `call'
/Users/macstore1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.6@lixibox/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:649:in `call'
/Users/macstore1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.6@lixibox/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
/Users/macstore1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.6@lixibox/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:88:in `call'
/Users/macstore1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.6@lixibox/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:88:in `_run_callbacks'
/Users/macstore1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.6@lixibox/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:776:in `_run_call_callbacks'
/Users/macstore1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.6@lixibox/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
/Users/macstore1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.6@lixibox/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
/Users/macstore1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.6@lixibox/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:73:in `call'
/Users/macstore1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.6@lixibox/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:78:in `call'
/Users/macstore1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.6@lixibox/gems/airbrake-4.3.0/lib/airbrake/rails/middleware.rb:13:in `call'
/Users/macstore1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.6@lixibox/gems/better_errors-2.1.1/lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:84:in `protected_app_call'
/Users/macstore1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.6@lixibox/gems/better_errors-2.1.1/lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:79:in `better_errors_call'
/Users/macstore1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.6@lixibox/gems/better_errors-2.1.1/lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:57:in `call'
/Users/macstore1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.6@lixibox/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
/Users/macstore1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.6@lixibox/gems/web-console-2.2.1/lib/web_console/middleware.rb:39:in `call'
/Users/macstore1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.6@lixibox/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
/Users/macstore1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.6@lixibox/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
/Users/macstore1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.6@lixibox/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
/Users/macstore1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.6@lixibox/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
/Users/macstore1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.6@lixibox/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
/Users/macstore1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.6@lixibox/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
/Users/macstore1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.6@lixibox/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
/Users/macstore1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.6@lixibox/gems/quiet_assets-1.1.0/lib/quiet_assets.rb:27:in `call_with_quiet_assets'
/Users/macstore1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.6@lixibox/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
/Users/macstore1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.6@lixibox/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:22:in `call'
/Users/macstore1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.6@lixibox/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/runtime.rb:18:in `call'
/Users/macstore1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.6@lixibox/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in `call'
/Users/macstore1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.6@lixibox/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
/Users/macstore1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.6@lixibox/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:113:in `call'
/Users/macstore1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.6@lixibox/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/sendfile.rb:113:in `call'
/Users/macstore1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.6@lixibox/gems/airbrake-4.3.0/lib/airbrake/user_informer.rb:16:in `_call'
/Users/macstore1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.6@lixibox/gems/airbrake-4.3.0/lib/airbrake/user_informer.rb:12:in `call'
/Users/macstore1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.6@lixibox/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:518:in `call'
/Users/macstore1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.6@lixibox/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/application.rb:164:in `call'
/Users/macstore1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.6@lixibox/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/content_length.rb:15:in `call'
/Users/macstore1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.6@lixibox/gems/thin-1.6.3/lib/thin/connection.rb:86:in `block in pre_process'
/Users/macstore1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.6@lixibox/gems/thin-1.6.3/lib/thin/connection.rb:84:in `catch'
/Users/macstore1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.6@lixibox/gems/thin-1.6.3/lib/thin/connection.rb:84:in `pre_process'
/Users/macstore1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.6@lixibox/gems/thin-1.6.3/lib/thin/connection.rb:53:in `process'
/Users/macstore1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.6@lixibox/gems/thin-1.6.3/lib/thin/connection.rb:39:in `receive_data'
/Users/macstore1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.6@lixibox/gems/eventmachine-1.0.7/lib/eventmachine.rb:187:in `run_machine'
/Users/macstore1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.6@lixibox/gems/eventmachine-1.0.7/lib/eventmachine.rb:187:in `run'
/Users/macstore1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.6@lixibox/gems/thin-1.6.3/lib/thin/backends/base.rb:73:in `start'
/Users/macstore1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.6@lixibox/gems/thin-1.6.3/lib/thin/server.rb:162:in `start'
/Users/macstore1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.6@lixibox/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/handler/thin.rb:19:in `run'
/Users/macstore1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.6@lixibox/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/server.rb:286:in `start'
/Users/macstore1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.6@lixibox/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:80:in `start'
/Users/macstore1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.6@lixibox/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:80:in `block in server'
/Users/macstore1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.6@lixibox/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `tap'
/Users/macstore1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.6@lixibox/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `server'
/Users/macstore1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.6@lixibox/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
/Users/macstore1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.6@lixibox/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/macstore1/projects/lixibox/bin/rails:8:in `require'
/Users/macstore1/projects/lixibox/bin/rails:8:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/macstore1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.6@lixibox/gems/spring-1.3.6/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `load'
/Users/macstore1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.6@lixibox/gems/spring-1.3.6/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `call'
/Users/macstore1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.6@lixibox/gems/spring-1.3.6/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
/Users/macstore1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.6@lixibox/gems/spring-1.3.6/lib/spring/client.rb:26:in `run'
/Users/macstore1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.6@lixibox/gems/spring-1.3.6/bin/spring:48:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/macstore1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.6@lixibox/gems/spring-1.3.6/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `load'
/Users/macstore1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.6@lixibox/gems/spring-1.3.6/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/macstore1/projects/lixibox/bin/spring:13:in `require'
/Users/macstore1/projects/lixibox/bin/spring:13:in `<top (required)>'
bin/rails:3:in `load'
bin/rails:3:in `<main>' ``

Comment: Where did you put the `rescue_from` block ?

Comment: I putted it in ```app/controllers/api/v1/defaults.rb```.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe there is an error in your API somewhere. The following should work (tested with Grape 0.13.0):

```
module Api
  class API < Grape::API
    rescue_from Grape::Exceptions::ValidationErrors do |e|
      error! e.message, 404
    end

    resource '/avatars' do
      params do
        requires :avatar, type: Rack::Multipart::UploadedFile
      end
      post '/' do
        {
          filename: params.avatar.filename,
          file_type: params.avatar.type
        }
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Also, if you define a `rescue_from :all` block, be sure to do it as the last block. By the way, Grape has a pretty good [documentation](https://github.com/ruby-grape/grape/blob/v0.13.0/README.md).